# ¿Pedir login cuando se ingrese el link de mi pagina?

Tags: html, hosting

Subi mi pagina web a 000WebHost, al momento de entrar te pide login y todo bien.

El problema viene cuando pongo el login de alguna pagina que este dentro, no se si me explico

Si pongo el link "Pagina.com/Otrapagina" no me pide login
Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de que cuando ingrese me pida logearme y despues me redireccione a la pagina a la que estaba intentando acceder

Comment: ¿El login lo creaste tú mismo? o ¿es algo que provee el hosting que estás usando?

Comment: El login lo he creado yo mismo:(

Comment: Puedes anexar el código de tu login explicandolo, sin ver el código es difícil ayudarte

Comment: Facil, en la subpagina lo primero que haces es comprobar si el usuario esta logueado. En caso negativo redireccionas a tu pagina de login con un parametro que indique la subpagina. Este valor lo pones en un input hidden de tu formulario de login y cuando el usuario se loguee redireccionas a esa pagina.

Comment: Estos sistemas de usuario registrado suelen funcionar con Sesiones.

Cuando haces un Login correcto, deberías almacenar en una variable de sesión que el usuario ha aportado las credenciales de acceso necesarias para navegar por el resto de páginas de tu sitio Web.

Cómo dice el compañero @JDev, luego lo único que tendrías que hacer es comprobar en todas las páginas internas si esta variable de sesión tiene el valor que le diste cuando un usuario accede correctamente y listos.

Si nos cuentas algo más de tu proyecto podremos ayudarte con mayores garantías de éxito.